# How to copy text and add a title attribute using jquery

Tags: jquery

How to copy page title from below code and create title attribute with that text?

This is what the code looks like:

```
<li class="item"><a href="..."><i class="fas fa-home"></i>Home Page</a></li>
<li class="item"><a href="..."><i class="fas fa-phone"></i>Contact</a></li>
<li class="item"><a href="..."><i class="fas fa-user"></i>User Page</a></li>
```

This is what I want the code to look like:

```
<li class="item"><a href="..." title="Home Page"><i class="fas fa-home"></i>Home Page</a></li>
<li class="item"><a href="..." title="Contact"><i class="fas fa-phone"></i>Contact</a></li>
<li class="item"><a href="..." title="User Account"><i class="fas fa-user"></i>User Account</a></li>
```

Script that almost works:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    jQuery(function($){
        $('.item a').attr('title', function(){
            return $(this).find('').attr('title');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

#### JavaScript:

```js
var links = document.querySelectorAll('.item a');
links.forEach(element => {
    element.setAttribute("title", element.textContent);
    console.log(element);
});
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="item"><a href="..."><i class="fas fa-home"></i>Home Page</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="..."><i class="fas fa-phone"></i>Contact</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="..."><i class="fas fa-user"></i>User Page</a></li>
</ul>
```

#### jQuery:

```js
$("li a").each(function() {
  $(this).attr("title", this.textContent);
  console.log(this);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="item"><a href="..."><i class="fas fa-home"></i>Home Page</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="..."><i class="fas fa-phone"></i>Contact</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="..."><i class="fas fa-user"></i>User Page</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your code is because you're using `find()` incorrectly, and returning the `title` (which is empty as that's what you're trying to set) instead of the text within the element.

To achieve what you need you can provide a function to `prop()` which returns the `text()` content within the element, to set as the `title`:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('.item a').prop('title', function() {
    return $(this).text();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="item"><a href="..."><i class="fas fa-home"></i>Home Page</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="..."><i class="fas fa-phone"></i>Contact</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="..."><i class="fas fa-user"></i>User Page</a></li>
</ul>
```